# Small Class of a Large Class

Tags: c++, class, return

I am doing a project in which i need to return a class but the class has a lot of member functions but i just want to return specific variables. The class is like this

```
class CA
{
public:
var1;
var2;
var3;
member_func();
member_func();
member_func();
QMutex      memoryMutex_mono; //another class
};
```

Is there any way so that i can only return the first three variables without returning all the member functions. Also there are total 15 variables with 6 member functions.

Please guide me in this project.

Thanks

Comment: Why would it matter how many member functions there are? They don't take up space in the objects, only the member variables does.

Comment: Returning member functions?

Comment: Actually this class also has another class in it which in turn depends on many other functions. so that's why i only want to return the variables. please see the edited question.

Comment: You can:
Put those three variables in a `struct X`. Then have an object of `X` as a member in your class. And then return that member.

Comment: Dear SAM, I don't want to edit the original class as that class depends on a lot of other classes and also other classes depends on this class so changing original class will create more problems. I want to just get hold of variables

Comment: Still you can do that... Instead of having `X` as a member, you can create an object of `X` from those three members and return that object.

Comment: Yes... pretty much like in my example answer a bit lower down :) You can either add a "get" function which is the usual way, and won't have any affect on your other depenencies since its a very simple function. Or you access each member externally (since they are public) and do it that way.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want a class with less member functions.

You can solve that by using inheritance, by making a more basic class that handles the bare minimum (and which will be the one you use) that is inherited by another class with more member functions.

Something like

```
struct BasicObject
{
    var1;
    var2;
    var3;
    member_func1();
}

struct FullObject : public BasicObject
{
    member_func2();
    member_func3();
}
```

But like I said in my comment, it wouldn't actually matter for the size of the object, as only member variables takes up space in an object, not its member functions.

Comment: Dear Sir, Thanks for the reply. I replied for the above comment on the above comment. Now for this actually i don't want to change the original class because that class is depends on a lot of other classes and also other classes depends on this class..i just want to get a small class of the variables.

Comment: @SaadSaadi Can't you have the `FullObject` class by named the same as your current class, and just create the `BasicObject` class containing the member variables? The code using your existing class only needs to be recompiled, they won't actually have to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you only want to get at the some of the data, so you can define a struct to hold that data:

```
typedef struct smallDataUnit
{
    int a;
    float b;
    uint32_t c;
}
```

And then use a "get" member function to return the data you want:

```
smallDataUnit member_func_get_small_data()
{
    smallDataUnit data;
    data.a = member_a;
    data.b = member_b;
    data.c = member_c;

    return data;
}
```